# Multiple Kable Tables with Images

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to create multiple tables using `kable` from a csv file, but the requirement is that I need to also put an image in the table as per the below image. The entire image needs to be in the left column. Is this possible?

[image: Sample Output]

The dataframe looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(Amount= c('$25', '$45', '$75'), 
               Rate = c('1%', '1%', '3%'), 
               Location = c('Germany', 'Switzerland', 'England'),
               ImageName= c('GE.png', 'BE.png', 'CE.png'),
               Status = c('Sold','Unsold','Sold')
               )
```

So far my R code is

````
---
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: ReferenceDoc.docx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

df<-read.csv('Productdata.csv')
```

```{r loops, echo=F, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{

print(kable(df[i,]))
}
```
````

Im really not sure how I can enter an image like that in my RMarkdown for WORD.

Comment: Do you absolutely need the Product column as it is shown here or can you live with Amount, Rate and Location as columns (ie a single row per property)?

Comment: Yes I need the product column.

Answer (score 11):

Here's an approach using `kable`, along with `kableExtra` functions to take care of some of the formatting. So far, I've only been able to render this properly to html. I'll update if I can make this work in Word. In the code below, I used some images I happened to have lying around. Just run the same `sprintf` function on your original `ImageName` column to get the appropriate `rmarkdown` tagging for your images.

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

#df<-read.csv('Productdata.csv')
df<-data.frame(Amount= c('$25', '$45', '$75'), 
               Rate = c('1%', '1%', '3%'), 
               Location = c('Germany', 'Switzerland', 'England'),
               ImageName= c('GE.png', 'BE.png', 'CE.png'),
               Status = c('Sold','Unsold','Sold')
               )

# Change to names of my local images
df$ImageName =c("mal2.jpg",
                "serenity2.jpg",
                "blue_sun2.jpg")

# Add appropriate rmarkdown tagging
df$ImageName = sprintf("![](%s)", df$ImageName)
```

```{r loops, echo=F, results="asis"}
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

  # Select desired row
  d = df[i, ]

  # Change name of ImageName column to Status value
  names(d)[grep("ImageName", names(d))] = as.character(d[["Status"]])

  # Convert data to "long" format
  d = d %>% 
    select(-Status) %>% 
    gather(Product, value, Amount:Location) %>% 
    rename(` ` = value)

  # Render table using kableExtra for formatting
  print(kable(d, format="html") %>% 
          kable_styling(full_width=FALSE) %>% 
          collapse_rows(columns=1, valign="top"))
}
```
````

And here's what the html output file looks like:

[image]

Comment: That looks awesome as well. Thank you, I wish there was a proper way to do this in WORD.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may bump up against the limits of `kable`, but here is a very not elegant way to do something similar with `htmlTable`. Notice that the images are relative to the directory you are running the Rmd from, or you can use links to URLs.

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  word_document:
    reference_docx: ReferenceDoc.docx
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(htmlTable)

x <- 0
df <- data.frame( Status = c('Sold','Unsold','Sold'),
           Image = c('images/fwhm1.jpg', 'images/ridges-shade.jpg', 'images/sep16-2018.jpg'),
           Amount= c('$25', '$45', '$75'), 
           Rate = c('1%', '1%', '3%'), 
           Location = c('Germany', 'Switzerland', 'England')
           )
df$Image <- sprintf('![](%s){width=150px}', df$Image)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   x <- t(df[i,])
   new.df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=2,nrow=2))
   new.df[1,1] <- paste(x[1],x[2],sep="<br>")
   new.df[1,2] <- paste0(rownames(x)[3:5], ": ", x[3:5], collapse="<br>")
   colnames(new.df) <- NULL
   rownames(new.df) <- NULL
   print( htmlTable(new.df, 
      css.cell="padding-left: .5em; padding-right: .5em; align: left; align: left; vertical-align: top;",
   rnames=FALSE) )
}
```
````

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I also opened the HTML file that was rendered in Word, and was able to shrink the images and add borders -- the table structure was retained. It looked like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input. I would really love this exact same output in WORD. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible, yes, but that would require a different kind of solution. The `kable` and `htmlTable` do better with HTML, and packages like `flextable` do better with rendering tables to Word and PDF in my opinion. Would recommend that you repost a new question, maybe include my solution as a starting point, then specifically request to find a Word solution. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks again. But my question does say it needs to be WORD (last sentence). I will wait a bit more time, then will repost if no one sees it.

Comment: Oh! That was waaaaaaay down there at the bottom. Sorry for missing it.

Comment: I just tried using Word to open the HTML file that can be rendered from the code above. Except for having to shrink the images, the table structure was retained and it was also easy to add borders. I added the screen shot above.

Comment: You have been a major help! Thank you