# Image aspect ratio in kableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I'm trying to insert images into a table using kableExtra. I know I have to use `spec_image` to specify the size. However the images have different dimensions and one size wouldn't fit all.

How do I rescale each image. I tried using `magick` to obtain the image dimensions into vectors and use something like: `spec_image(imagepaths, image_heights, image_widths)` but that didn't work.

Secondly I want the text to be aligned such that it's in the middle of the image. `valign` didn't give the desired result.

Would appreciate some help.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    extra_dependencies: ["float"]
    template: NULL
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: false
    latex_engine: pdflatex
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{graphicx}
---


```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(kableExtra)

first_column <- c("mol1.png", "mol2.png", "mol3.png")
second_column <- c('2', '3', '4')
third_column <- c('1', '4', '7')

df <- data.frame(mol = "",
                 second = second_column,
                 third = third_column)


df %>% kbl(booktabs = T, linesep = "", caption = "Test" ,valign = 't') %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, image = spec_image(first_column, 200, 200)) 
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will get you part of the way there by vertically aligning the text in the non-image cells.

````
```
    df  |> 
      kbl(booktabs = T, 
          caption = "Test") |> 
      column_spec(1, 
                  width = "25mm",
                  image = spec_image(first_column, 300, 300),
                  latex_valign = "m")

```
````

It would be helpful to understand how you want to rescale the images, and include examples of the images in the question so that the question is reproducible. Do you want to retain the original aspect ratio of the figures? Or the original size?

It seems as if KableExtra makes the images the same size, which sort of makes sense to end up with a consistent table.

Here is a link which may be of use: [Multiple Kable Tables with Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914941/multiple-kable-tables-with-images)

[image]

Comment: I want the correct aspect ratio subject to the constraint that say the height does not go beyond a certain limit. I was hoping that there would be a scaling option that would allow me to scale each figure.